# How do i fetch specific data from an html webpage

Tags: c#, html, wpf

I am making an mp3 song fetcher in WPF. What it does is to fetch all the results from a web page. The problem i am having is that it fetches irrelevant data like tags, links(not download ones) etc.

What i want is to fetch only the results and download links from the web page and display it in a List Box.

Any Help would be appreciated!!

Like from this link: http://mp3skull.com/mp3/move_that_dope.html

Comment: What have you *tried*? What worked? What didn't?

Comment: Try this : http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ you can parse homepages with this lib an filter for the content/link you need

Comment: @Piskvor unfortunately i didn't tried anything cuz i didn't know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very simple to do this with [HtmlAgilityPack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack). You can just load document, and then select tags that you need using simple [XPath expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

```
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace com.mp3skull.scrapper
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var p = new Program();
            HtmlNodeCollection songs = p.GetSongNodesFromPage("http://mp3skull.com/mp3/move_that_dope.html");
            p.WriteSongsToConsole(songs);

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue..");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        private readonly HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();

        private HtmlNodeCollection GetSongNodesFromPage(string pageUri)
        {
            HtmlDocument document = web.Load(pageUri);
            HtmlNode documentNode = document.DocumentNode;
            return documentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='song_html']");
        }

        private void WriteSongsToConsole(HtmlNodeCollection songs)
        {
            foreach (HtmlNode s in songs)
            {
                HtmlNode titleNode = s.SelectSingleNode(".//b"); // Title is bold
                string title = titleNode.InnerText;

                HtmlNode downloadLinkNode = s.SelectSingleNode(".//a[@style='color:green;']");  // Download links is green
                string downloadLink = downloadLinkNode.Attributes["href"].Value;

                HtmlNode songInfoNode = s.SelectSingleNode("./div[@class='left']");
                string songInfo = GetSongInfoLine(songInfoNode);

                Console.WriteLine("Title: {0}\t", title);
                Console.WriteLine("Information: {0}\t", songInfo);
                Console.WriteLine("Download link: {0}\t", downloadLink);

                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }

        private string GetSongInfoLine(HtmlNode songInfoNode)
        {
            var textNodes = songInfoNode.Descendants("#text");
            var infoBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var node in textNodes)
            {
                if (infoBuilder.Length > 0)
                {
                    infoBuilder.Append(", ");
                }
                infoBuilder.Append(node.InnerText.Trim());
            }
            return infoBuilder.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks!!! From the look of it, it seems working and completing my needs but i will let you know if it works.!! Thanks Again...!!!

Comment: It Worked like a charm but i need to extract the song info also, if you know how to do this please tell!!

Comment: @TheGaMeR123 , Updated. But please try to experiment more by yourself.

Comment: hey man, i need your help again. the code you provided above only extracts info for the first song. Any Suggestions on how to fix that??

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea where to start, then learning Regular Expressions is where to go.

With regular expressions you can dissect the HTML code into relevant tags and then do whatever you whant to do.

This place is really one of the best ones I know about regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Also, for testing regular expressions, there is a nifty tool called The regex coach, very useful for testing and learning about regular expressions: http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/